# Why datagrid.CurrentRow.index in wpf is not working but in winforms its workings?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image]

Why datagrid.CurrentRow.index in wpf is not working but in winforms its workings?

Comment: Can you please try hovering your mouse cursor over the RED error message and see why its complaining?

Comment: I think there's SelectedIndex.

Comment: i try using SelectedIndex.

Comment: `CurrentItem` should be the data item bound to the currently selected row, however.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because `WPF DataGrid` doesn't have a `CurrentRow` property just like in `WinForms DataGridView`.